# Spring _thymeleaf login page and basic Authentication

Tags: spring, authentication, thymeleaf

In my application I use  basic authentication. I have 2 types the users. 
WORKER and OTHER. 
Worker is an simple monitoring module that send to REST API request to storing in database.

OTHERS users will use  WebClient to access application data.  There I would like use basic authentication too.  How storing on user side his  login and password ?

Comment: anybody ???  :(  it realy block me

Comment: Do you want to know spring security and implement basic authentication? http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.3.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/

Comment: Spring security is used on REST API site.    But the problem is  storing the information on client site to dont need all time asked user to send login and password. I  want  to know how integrate client with rest api

Comment: to precise : In Deskop Client I can storing user information in memory ( variable). But on Web Client when I use or Angular or like in this example Spring +Themeleaf ???

Comment: If you want to authenticate REST API client without prompting user credentials all the time, you can go with oath2 implementation https://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/docs/oauth2.html

Comment: No .. I want still use BasicAuthentication, but only storing this info on client side, to send it each time  in request header.

Comment: I cannot understand what do you mean by storing this info on the client side. You need to keep a session on your client side with relevant credential to access REST api

Comment: In example of DesktopApplication. I can storing cretential information in variable, and sending it with all request to REST API..  How do it in Web Client ??  Use  cookies ?? or there is others methods ? for example if I would like also storing user permission safetly